# Reverse Feed in Dot matrix Printer using Javascript

Tags: javascript, feed, reverse

I am having a Java web application which uses the javascript function window.print() for printing receipts using a browser. The Printer is a dot-matrix printer(TVS MSP 450 STAR). However, after I print and tear off the first receipt, the printer does not automatically reverse feed, and so the second receipt does not print in the correct position. Could you please suggest a way how to reverse feed a paper in dot-matrix printer using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution for the above problem. There is a printer setting called 'Tear Off' which if enabled automatically reverses the feed for every print to the starting position of the next receipt. Thus, this does not require any software change. It can be easily handled by making changes in the hardware configuration.